# CSS background image not showing on mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css, background

I need some help with displaying my background on mobile devices, the current code works on my browser but when I visit it on a mobile device the background crawls up to the top and is not visible, also the div for the other image does not react to the % i gave it. (I really have to use percents becouse it will make the site better for any mobile device)

I had this code working, but it was not in CSS but made in HTML itself, now i want to use CSS becouse you can not download the background anymore as picture.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="favicon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"/>
<title>Rolling Barrel :: Sport & Game</title>
<meta name="description" content="De Rolling Barrel is een revolutionair idee waarmee sporten & gamen een compleet nieuwe dimensie krijgt.">
<style>
body#background {
 background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}

div {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 11%;
 width: 37%;
 height: 70%;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

div img {
 width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="background">
<div>
    <img src="text.png" alt=""/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I used my Android phone to view the site btw.
Hope someone can help me or give me a push in the right direction.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Either just put the background-image attribute on #background or just put it on body (in the css) no need for both. I understand you may want to contain the image, in which case you can just use the element name (#background) and set an overflow to none if the image bleeds.

If you have any more questions or need help with this, just comment and I'll set up a JS Fiddle for you.